# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDrive

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc

I’m implementing a dynamic web project (HTML, jsp, Servlet, Java and SQL).
When I “run on server” the HTML, everything works fine, except that I’m getting a

> ClassNotFoundException - com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
>   when loading the SQL driver
>   Class.forName ("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

on a Java class.

For testing, I created a main class (in the same project and package to check the java build path) using the same java code for the database. When I run this class (`Main`) using “run application”, the code works fine and I have access to the database.

Do you have any idea why loading the SQL driver is not working when I run the project using “run on server”?

Comment: where did you add jar in web project? WEB-INF -> lib?

Comment: Which are you using? `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` as in the error, or `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` as in the `Class.forName` call you claim to use? The first is for the very old SQL Server 2000 driver which you shouldn't be using, and the other is for more recent drivers. Please provide the code used and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: And you shouldn't need `Class.forName` with modern drivers anyway, as JDBC has been using SPI for years.

Comment: @chrylis That is not entirely true, for example in web applications if the driver is deployed in the WAR (and you want to use `DriverManager` instead of a data source), you'll still need to explicitly load the driver. Automatic driver loading only works for drivers on the initial classpath. Which also explains the difference between running a standalone `Main` class and the web application.